# Way to determine the number of seconds since the epoch?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

What is the easiest way to get `time.now()` in Python where:

```
time.now() = seconds since epoch GMT at the time time.now() is called
```

There seems to be considerable information on how to convert from `struct_time` to seconds, but I was hoping for a single built-in function that just returns seconds since epoch GMT.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question is a horribly convoluted and expensive way to just do `time.time()` - which is the normal standard clean way to get seconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug around for a while.. I'm hoping someone has something better but here's my solution:

```
import time
time.time()
```

Comment: Yeah, `time.time()`.